# Titanium Backup: How to schedule backup verification?

Tags: backup, titanium-backup

How do I schedule a "Verify backups" action in Titanium backup?

The list of available actions in the "Add new schedule" dialog seem to include all standard backup actions (for example various backup and restore actions) except "Verify backups". Is there a way to achieve this?

The Titanium backup FAQ recommends performing a verification on all backups, but if it cannot be scheduled it has to be done manually, which defeats the purpose (and convenience) of scheduling in the first place.